# Does AngularJS really need jQuery?

Tags: angularjs

I was reading that AngularJS comes with a lite version of jQuery. However I keep hearing reference to people who talk about Angular and jQuery going together. I even checked out [ng-grid](http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/) and noticed that it says:

> Angular Data Grid written in AngularJS and jQuery by the AngularUI Team

So if I do use Angular just when would I need jQuery and what does the version that comes as part of AngularJS not provide?

Comment: [docs- explanation of what jQlite does provide](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element)  easily found in search of `jQlite`

Answer (score 74, accepted):

jQLite is a very stripped-down version of jQuery. jQLite is enough for angular to work. This is to minimize dependencies.

Yet, if you load jQuery *before* angular, then angular will use jQuery.

Most of the time, you do not need to use jQuery. Even so much that, for beginners, it is advised to leave out jQuery completely as there would be a tendency to use jQuery when there is an easy / angular way. There has been so many examples on this (mostly showing and hiding elements through jQuery when there are `ngShow` and `ngHide` directives).

Later on, when you start to write directives, you then may need to add jQuery.

`ngGrid` possibly does many things for which `jqLite` would not suffice. Thus, they used `jQuery`.

Documentation and features of jqLite:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element

Comment: Well said! The most common jQuery usages I see are for animation when CSS transitions simply aren't enough and for using complex existing plugins where the rewrite payoff may not be immediately there.