# Removing jQLite (mini-jQuery) from Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jqlite

Angularjs use [very stripped version on jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722066/does-angularjs-really-need-jquery) called `jQLite` (or `mini-jQuery` in some websites). If you add a reference to main jQuery, Angularjs will use your main jQuery and I **always** have reference to main jQuery in my applications. So for reducing size of Angularjs, I want to remove jQLite from Angularjs file. What is easy (and safe) way to do this?

Comment: jqLite is -tiny-, I think you would save yourself a lot of trouble by focusing on other things.

Comment: Guess there won't be a proper way to do this until Angular provides custom builds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the official answer, answered by one of the creators -

https://plus.google.com/+IgorMinar/posts/EgjErc6NdrD

and another discussion related to it.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/PPKd5vu6FYk

They mention everything I would have said.