# AngularJs - How to not using jquery when calling bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new in AngularJs. I try to make web with AngularJs and Bootstrap. when I call bootstrap modal I use this script :

```
    $scope.here = function here(f) {
         $('#smallModal').modal();
         $('#contentin').html(f);   
}
```

that code I call use `ng-click=here('test')`
in my header html i still use Jquery library. My question is , is it posiblle to unload jquery for call modal bootstrap who called with `$` prefix. I don't want to use any plugin except AngularJs

Comment: can use angular-ui directives that include a bootstrap modal without needing bootstrap.js

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make use of Bootstrap's modal, one option is to use [Angular-UI's Bootstrap](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap) (if that isn't what you're already using), which puts Bootstrap components into Angular directives for you. Specifically, you would inject the `$modal` service into whatever module needs to control the modal. Here's an [example](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) of how to use the `$modal` service.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of displaying model dialog out there. You can easily search with google. 
btw, AngularJS use jQuery - or jQuery lite in the backend.

Comment: angular has no jQuery dependency. This is not really a very valid answer to the question

Comment: Angular does have a dependency on jqlite. A stripped down version of jQuery.  If you require jQuery first it will use that instead. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15725017/124220

Comment: well i mean the lite version of it. It is not a strong dependency