# Why need refer the Jquery script in angularjs project?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Why we call the Jquery script before call the angular script?

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
```

If i call the jquery script, then why i go to angularjs? Any possible way there implement angularjs without using jquery?

Comment: angularjs already has its own jq lite version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, Angular does not depend on jQuery - you can use Angular perfectly fine without using jQuery. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background) on the conceptual shift and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722066/does-angularjs-really-need-jquery) on whether or not it's needed.

Second of all - you refer to jQuery *before Angular* because if jQuery is included then Angular will *use it* internally over its more limited implementation [jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element). This means you can use the entire jQuery API and not just the limited jqLite API everywhere in Angular (typically, in directives).

Technically, you can include jQuery later as well as long as you do it before the DOMContentLoaded event (that's `$(document).ready` in jQuery speak).

Comment: For the first time am learning from your post on how to post a quality answer:)

Answer (score -1):

You can go fine with angular.js alone without using jQuery if you need it's core features.

Here you can read more :

[`Does AngularJS really need jQuery?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722066/does-angularjs-really-need-jquery)

Working Plnker with only [`Angular`](http://plnkr.co/edit/eZhDz8hIPjM6sjcnAOhz?p=preview)