# jQuery.load HTML containing AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm having trouble loading an HTML file that contains AngularJS code!

Here are my snippets:

**page1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>   
    <script src="jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>        
    <div id="content">
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#content').load('page2.html#body');
        });        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**page2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">        
        {{ value }}
    </div>

    <script>
    //<![CDATA[
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);  
        app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.value = "hello world!";
        });    
    //]]>
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**page2** alone works just fine! But when I try to load it inside **page1**, I get the following error message:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…
>   at HTMLDocument.eval (eval at globalEval (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2), :294:192)
>   at i (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular needs jQuery to work (*to be exact, [it needs jQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722066/does-angularjs-really-need-jquery)*). You should import it also on page2.html, before `angular.min.js`.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>
    <script src="jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: After adding the jquery it worked! But I am confused now, when I load the page2 alone, it works without explicit importing the jquery.js, can anyone explain why? just curious